# Aplicación de NodeJS se detiene sin errores - Graphql / Fastify /mongoose

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, mongodb, graphql

Hola muy buenas tardes a todos.

En el día de hoy tengo un problema y es que mi aplicación de NodeJS de repente se detiene sin ningún error ni nada por el estilo.

*Nota: ya me había pasado con mongoose, me equivoqué en una letra dentro de los modelos y cada vez que corría la app no me decía nada, hasta que lo logré resolver yo sólo, pero claro, eso no debería de pasar, debe de decir al menos un error o advertencia*

Después de investigar un rato ya encontré cual es el código que hace que no corra la aplicación, pero no tengo ni idea de cómo arreglarlo.
El código es dentro de los `TypeDefs` / `Schemas` de `Graphql`, tódo el código (que si funciona), es:

Nombre Archivo: *Employee.schema.ts*

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

export default gql`
  type Query {
    "Loguear un empleado de una empresa"
    loginEmployee(input: LoginInput!): String!
    viewer(token: String!): TokenPayload!
  }

  type Mutation {
    "Crear un nuevo empleado de una empresa"
    createEmployee(input: EmployeeInput!, key: String!): Boolean!
  }

  "Información necesaria para el logueo de un empleado"
  input LoginInput {
    "Correo electronico del empleado"
    mail: String!
    "Contraseña del empleado"
    pass: String!
  }

  enum EmployeeRoles {
    admin
    employee
  }

  # type TokenPayload {
  #   role: EmployeeRoles!;
  #   "Id del usuario"
  #   sub: ID!;
  #   "Email del usuario"
  #   mail: String!;
  #   "Nombre del usuario"
  #   name: String!;
  #   "Id de la empresa a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   businessId: ID!;
  #   "Nombre de la empresa a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   businessName: String!;
  #   "Id de la tienda o local a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   storeId: ID;
  #   "Nombre de la tienda o local a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   storeName: String;
  #   "avatar del usuario"
  #   avatar: String!;
  # }

  "Información necesaria para crear un empleado"
  input EmployeeInput {
    "Nombre del empleado"
    name: String!
    "Id de la empresa del empleado"
    business: ID!
    "Id de la tienda del empleado"
    store: ID
    "Correo electronico del empleado"
    mail: String!
    "Contraseña del empleado"
    pass: String!
  }
`;
```

Ahora, el código que causa problemas el que está comentado, osea:

```
  # type TokenPayload {
  #   role: EmployeeRoles!;
  #   "Id del usuario"
  #   sub: ID!;
  #   "Email del usuario"
  #   mail: String!;
  #   "Nombre del usuario"
  #   name: String!;
  #   "Id de la empresa a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   businessId: ID!;
  #   "Nombre de la empresa a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   businessName: String!;
  #   "Id de la tienda o local a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   storeId: ID;
  #   "Nombre de la tienda o local a la que pertenece el usuario"
  #   storeName: String;
  #   "avatar del usuario"
  #   avatar: String!;
  # }
```

La verdad no tengo ni idea de porqué no funciona, es más traté de definir un tipo cualquiera por ejemplo:

```
type Foo {
 hello: String!
}
```

pero aún así no funciona, cosa que me deja aún más perdido, ya he investigado un montón pero no he logrado nada.
Adjunto algunos archivos que podrían ser útiles:

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "lintufly-sales",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "**/*.test.ts",
      "**/*.spec.ts",
      ".git",
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "watch": [
      "src",
      "schema"
    ],
    "exec": "node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register ./src/index.ts",
    "ext": "ts, graphql"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "npm install --production",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "start:dev": "node dist/index.js",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "build": "tsc",
    "postbuild": "tscpaths -p tsconfig.json -s ./src -o ./dist",
    "indent": "prettier --write .",
    "docs": "jsdoc -c jsdoc.json",
    "autocannon": "ts-node ./__test__/auto/index.ts",
    "test": "jest --transformIgnorePatterns --runInBand -- index.spec.ts",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:open": "cd coverage/lcov-report && \"index.html\""
  },
  "jest": {
    "modulePaths": [
      "./"
    ],
    "roots": [
      "./"
    ],
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "./jest.setup.js"
    ],
    "verbose": false,
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "@config/(.*)": [
        "<rootDir>/src/config/$1"
      ],
      "@functions/(.*)": [
        "<rootDir>/src/functions/$1"
      ],
      "@interfaces/(.*)": [
        "<rootDir>/src/interfaces/$1"
      ],
      "@models/(.*)": [
        "<rootDir>/src/models/$1"
      ],
      "@graphql/(.*)": [
        "<rootDir>/src/graphql/$1"
      ]
    }
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Jesús García",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "fastify": "^3.17.0",
    "fastify-cors": "^6.0.1",
    "fastify-helmet": "^5.3.1",
    "geoip-lite": "^1.4.2",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "graphql-middleware": "^6.0.10",
    "graphql-shield": "^7.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.4",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.5",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mercurius": "^7.7.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.13",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.18",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rollbar": "^2.22.0",
    "uuid": "^3.4.0",
    "validator": "^13.6.0",
    "winston": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/autocannon": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/geoip-lite": "^1.4.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "@types/mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.10",
    "@types/node": "^15.12.1",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.2",
    "@types/prompts": "^2.0.12",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@types/validator": "^13.1.3",
    "autocannon": "^7.3.0",
    "better-docs": "^2.3.2",
    "jest": "^27.0.4",
    "jsdoc": "^3.6.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "prettier": "^2.3.0",
    "prompts": "^2.4.1",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "tscpaths": "^0.0.9",
    "typescript": "^3.9.9"
  }
}
```

*Archivo donde se juntan los schemas:*

```
import { mergeTypeDefs } from 'graphql-tools';
import { print } from 'graphql';

import business from '@schema/business.schema';
// import client from '@schema/client.schema';
// import egress from '@schema/egress.schema';
import employee from '@schema/employee.schema';
// import income from '@schema/income.schema';
// import product from '@schema/product.schema';
// import sale from '@schema/sale.schema';
import store from '@schema/store.schema';

// leo todos los archivos de schemas y luego los uno
export default print(mergeTypeDefs([business, employee, store]));
```

*Archivo dónde configuro el servidor: (NO es dónde lanzo la app)*:

```
import { applyMiddleware } from 'graphql-middleware';
import { makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import fastify, { FastifyInstance } from 'fastify';
import helmet from 'fastify-helmet';
import mercurius from 'mercurius';
import cors from 'fastify-cors';

import {
  errorController,
  handlerErrors,
  notFoundController,
} from '@utils/handler.errors';

import authServices from '@services/auth.services';

import permissions from '@graphql/permissions';
import resolvers from '@graphql/resolvers';
import schema from '@graphql/schema';

import { GrahpqlCtx } from '@interfaces';

import { initConn } from './db.config';

/**
 * Clase que inicializa el servidor
 */
export class App {
  private app: FastifyInstance;
  private port: number;

  /**
   * Constructor para incializar la instancia de fastify, el puerto, y las demás
   * configuraciones
   * @param {number} port puerto en el que va a escuchar el servidor
   */
  constructor(port?: number) {
    this.app = fastify({
      logger: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      trustProxy: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    });
    this.port = port || parseInt(process.env.PORT!);

    this.middlewares();
    this.handlers();
  }

  /**
   * Middlewares de la aplicación
   */
  private middlewares() {
    this.app.register(cors, {
      methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
      optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
    });

    this.app.register(mercurius, {
      schema: applyMiddleware(
        makeExecutableSchema({
          typeDefs: schema,
          resolvers,
        }),
        permissions,
      ),
      graphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
      context: (req): GrahpqlCtx => ({
        user: authServices.authToken(req.headers['x-auth-token'] as string),
      }),
    });

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') this.app.register(helmet);
    else
      this.app.get('/', ({}, reply) => {
        reply.send('');
      });
  }

  /**
   * Handlers de la aplicación
   */
  public handlers() {
    this.app.setErrorHandler(errorController);
    this.app.setNotFoundHandler(notFoundController);
  }

  /**
   * Función para poner a escuchar al servidor en el puerto antes indicado y
   * además, inicializar la conexión con mongodb
   */
  public async listen() {
    try {
      await initConn();
      await this.app.listen(this.port, '0.0.0.0');
    } catch (e) {
      handlerErrors(e, true);
    }
  }
}
```

*Archivo dónde corro la app*:

```
const temp = process.exit;
process.exit = function () {
  console.trace();
  process.exit = temp;
  process.exit();
};

import cluster from 'cluster';
import { cpus } from 'os';
const cpusLength = cpus().length;

//seteo el entorno actual de la aplicación
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'dev';

//import la configuración de los .env
import '@config/env.config';

import { logger } from '@config/logger.config';
import Master from '@config/clusters.config';
import { App } from '@config/server.config';

import { handlerErrors } from '@utils/handler.errors';

// handlear cuando no hay un reject
process.on('unhandledRejection', (e) => {
  handlerErrors(e, true);
});

//handlear las exepciones desconocidas
process.on('uncaughtException', (e) => {
  handlerErrors(e, true);
});

//función que inicializa el servidor
(async () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev') {
    const app = new App();
    return app.listen();
  }

  //si estamos con el mastes, levantamos lo workes
  if (cluster.isMaster && cpusLength > 1) {
    const master = new Master({ cluster: cluster });

    //levantamos un worker por cada cpu
    for (let i = 0; i < cpusLength; i++) master.levantarWorker();

    cluster.on('exit', (worker) => {
      logger.error(`Cluster number: ${worker.id} is dead`);

      // levantamos un nuevo worker cuando uno muere
      master.levantarWorkerMuerto();
    });

    //si no estamos con el master, levantamos la aplicación
  } else {
    const app = new App();
    return app.listen();
  }
})();
```

Si alguien me puede ayudar sería genial, de verdad que es de los pocos errores que me deja completamente desconcertado y aparte debo de presentar avances en el trabajo y esto me deja totalmente estancado.

Gracias de antemano.

### Edit:

Se me olvidó decir lo que yo veo por consola, básicamente cuando lanzo la aplicación normal (osea con node), pues se inicia y de repente se sale.

Cuando la inicio con nodemon por lo menos me dice algo y es lo siguiente:

```
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Y ya, sólo me dice eso, no sé si sea de ayuda.